# How to create custom components in JavaFX 2.0 using FXML?

Tags: javafx-2, fxml

I can't seem to find any material on the subject. To give a more concrete example, let's say I want to create a simple component that combines a checkbox and a label. Then, populate a ListView with instances of this custom component.

UPDATE:
see my answer for complete code

UPDATE 2:
For an up-to-date tutorial, please, consult [the official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/custom_control.htm). There was a lot of [new stuff](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/whats_new2.htm) that was added in 2.2. Finally, the [Introduction to FXML](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html) covers pretty much everything you need to know about FXML.

UPDATE 3:
Hendrik Ebbers made an extremely helpful [blog post](http://www.guigarage.com/2012/11/custom-ui-controls-with-javafx-part-1/) about custom UI controls.

Comment: The custom control example in your 'official documentation' link is broken. In there are two methods that are not part of the API.

Comment: @danLeon first, it's not MY "official documentation". it's THE "official documentation" written by Oracle employees who are working on JavaFX. second, the code I'm linking to contains a working example of how to create custom components in JavaFX 2.2. most likely the version you have is older, hence missing methods. Here's a highlight from that page: "Before you start, ensure that the version of NetBeans IDE that you are using supports JavaFX 2.2"

Comment: You right! My IDE was under JavaFx 2.1, Thanks for comment. Now over 2.2, I deleted any previous java version in my computer.

Comment: Hi @Andrey, thanks for mentioning my post. You are doing very interesting stuff here. Never played with fxml and custom components before but it's a great way to outsource the layout. I think the outcome of this will be a new "custom controls" post in my series.

Comment: @HendrikEbbers that would be awesome. I'm looking forward to it.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**Update:** For an up-to-date tutorial, please, consult [the official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/custom_control.htm). There was a lot of [new stuff](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/whats_new2.htm) that was added in 2.2. Also, the [Introduction to FXML](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html) covers pretty much everything you need to know about FXML. Finally, Hendrik Ebbers made an extremely helpful [blog post](http://www.guigarage.com/2012/11/custom-ui-controls-with-javafx-part-1/) about custom UI controls.

---

After a few days of looking around the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/) and reading through some docs ([Intro to FXML](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html), [Getting started with FXML](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/fxml_get_started/jfxpub-fxml_get_started.htm) [Property binding](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm), [Future of FXML](http://fxexperience.com/2011/10/fxml-why-it-rocks-and-the-next-phase/)) I've come up with a fairly sensible solution.
The least straight-forward piece of information I learned from this little experiment was that the instance of a controller (declared with fx:controller in FXML) is held by the [FXMLLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html) that loaded the FXML file... Worst of all, this important fact is only mentioned in [one place](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#controllers) in all the docs I saw:

> a controller is generally only visible to the FXML loader that creates it

So, remember, in order to programmatically (from Java code) obtain a reference to the instance of a controller that was declared in FXML with `fx:controller` use [FXMLLoader.getController()](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#getController%28%29) (refer to the implementation of the ChoiceCell class below for a complete example).

Another thing to note is that [Property.bindBiderctional()](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/beans/property/Property.html#bindBidirectional%28javafx.beans.property.Property%29) will set the value of the calling property to the value of the property passed in as the argument. Given two boolean properties `target` (originally set to `false`) and `source` (initially set to `true`) calling `target.bindBidirectional(source)` will set the value of `target` to `true`. Obviously, any subsequent changes to either property will change the other property's value (`target.set(false)` will cause the value of `source` to be set to `false`):

```
BooleanProperty target = new SimpleBooleanProperty();//value is false
BooleanProperty source = new SimpleBooleanProperty(true);//value is true
target.bindBidirectional(source);//target.get() will now return true
target.set(false);//both values are now false
source.set(true);//both values are now true
```

Anyway, here is the complete code that demonstrates how FXML and Java can work together (as well as a few other useful things)

Package structure:

```
com.example.javafx.choice
  ChoiceCell.java
  ChoiceController.java
  ChoiceModel.java
  ChoiceView.fxml
com.example.javafx.mvc
  FxmlMvcPatternDemo.java
  MainController.java
  MainView.fxml
  MainView.properties
```

FxmlMvcPatternDemo.java

```
package com.example.javafx.mvc;

import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FxmlMvcPatternDemo extends Application
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException
    {
        Application.launch(FxmlMvcPatternDemo.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load
        (
            FxmlMvcPatternDemo.class.getResource("MainView.fxml"),
            ResourceBundle.getBundle(FxmlMvcPatternDemo.class.getPackage().getName()+".MainView")/*properties file*/
        );

        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

MainView.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<VBox
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
    fx:controller="com.example.javafx.mvc.MainController"

    prefWidth="300"
    prefHeight="400"
    fillWidth="false"
>
    <children>
        <Label text="%title" />
        <ListView fx:id="choicesView" />
        <Button text="Force Change" onAction="#handleForceChange" />
    </children>
</VBox>
```

MainView.properties

```
title=JavaFX 2.0 FXML MVC demo
```

MainController.java

```
package com.example.javafx.mvc;

import com.example.javafx.choice.ChoiceCell;
import com.example.javafx.choice.ChoiceModel;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class MainController implements Initializable
{
    @FXML
    private ListView<ChoiceModel> choicesView;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb)
    {
        choicesView.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<ChoiceModel>, ListCell<ChoiceModel>>()
        {
            public ListCell<ChoiceModel> call(ListView<ChoiceModel> p)
            {
                return new ChoiceCell();
            }
        });
        choicesView.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList
        (
            new ChoiceModel("Tiger", true),
            new ChoiceModel("Shark", false),
            new ChoiceModel("Bear", false),
            new ChoiceModel("Wolf", true)
        ));
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleForceChange(ActionEvent event)
    {
        if(choicesView != null && choicesView.getItems().size() > 0)
        {
            boolean isSelected = choicesView.getItems().get(0).isSelected();
            choicesView.getItems().get(0).setSelected(!isSelected);
        }
    }
}
```

ChoiceView.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<HBox
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"

    fx:controller="com.example.javafx.choice.ChoiceController"
>
    <children>
        <CheckBox fx:id="isSelectedView" />
        <Label fx:id="labelView" />
    </children>
</HBox>
```

ChoiceController.java

```
package com.example.javafx.choice;

import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class ChoiceController
{
    private final ChangeListener<String> LABEL_CHANGE_LISTENER = new ChangeListener<String>()
    {
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> property, String oldValue, String newValue)
        {
            updateLabelView(newValue);
        }
    };

    private final ChangeListener<Boolean> IS_SELECTED_CHANGE_LISTENER = new ChangeListener<Boolean>()
    {
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> property, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue)
        {
            updateIsSelectedView(newValue);
        }
    };

    @FXML
    private Label labelView;

    @FXML
    private CheckBox isSelectedView;

    private ChoiceModel model;

    public ChoiceModel getModel()
    {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(ChoiceModel model)
    {
        if(this.model != null)
            removeModelListeners();
        this.model = model;
        setupModelListeners();
        updateView();
    }

    private void removeModelListeners()
    {
        model.labelProperty().removeListener(LABEL_CHANGE_LISTENER);
        model.isSelectedProperty().removeListener(IS_SELECTED_CHANGE_LISTENER);
        isSelectedView.selectedProperty().unbindBidirectional(model.isSelectedProperty())
    }

    private void setupModelListeners()
    {
        model.labelProperty().addListener(LABEL_CHANGE_LISTENER);
        model.isSelectedProperty().addListener(IS_SELECTED_CHANGE_LISTENER);
        isSelectedView.selectedProperty().bindBidirectional(model.isSelectedProperty());
    }

    private void updateView()
    {
        updateLabelView();
        updateIsSelectedView();
    }

    private void updateLabelView(){ updateLabelView(model.getLabel()); }
    private void updateLabelView(String newValue)
    {
        labelView.setText(newValue);
    }

    private void updateIsSelectedView(){ updateIsSelectedView(model.isSelected()); }
    private void updateIsSelectedView(boolean newValue)
    {
        isSelectedView.setSelected(newValue);
    }
}
```

ChoiceModel.java

```
package com.example.javafx.choice;

import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class ChoiceModel
{
    private final StringProperty label;
    private final BooleanProperty isSelected;

    public ChoiceModel()
    {
        this(null, false);
    }

    public ChoiceModel(String label)
    {
        this(label, false);
    }

    public ChoiceModel(String label, boolean isSelected)
    {
        this.label = new SimpleStringProperty(label);
        this.isSelected = new SimpleBooleanProperty(isSelected);
    }

    public String getLabel(){ return label.get(); }
    public void setLabel(String label){ this.label.set(label); }
    public StringProperty labelProperty(){ return label; }

    public boolean isSelected(){ return isSelected.get(); }
    public void setSelected(boolean isSelected){ this.isSelected.set(isSelected); }
    public BooleanProperty isSelectedProperty(){ return isSelected; }
}
```

ChoiceCell.java

```
package com.example.javafx.choice;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.JavaFXBuilderFactory;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;

public class ChoiceCell extends ListCell<ChoiceModel>
{
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(ChoiceModel model, boolean bln)
    {
        super.updateItem(model, bln);

        if(model != null)
        {
            URL location = ChoiceController.class.getResource("ChoiceView.fxml");

            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
            fxmlLoader.setLocation(location);
            fxmlLoader.setBuilderFactory(new JavaFXBuilderFactory());

            try
            {
                Node root = (Node)fxmlLoader.load(location.openStream());
                ChoiceController controller = (ChoiceController)fxmlLoader.getController();
                controller.setModel(model);
                setGraphic(root);
            }
            catch(IOException ioe)
            {
                throw new IllegalStateException(ioe);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: glad to help. however, make sure you take a look at the links I provided in the update. a lot of new stuff was added in 2.2

Answer (score 10):

For JavaFx 2.1, You can create a custom FXML control component by this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import customcontrolexample.myCommponent.*?>

<VBox xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="customcontrolexample.FXML1Controller">
    <children>
        <MyComponent welcome="1234"/>
    </children>
</VBox>
```

Component code:

MyComponent.java

```
package customcontrolexample.myCommponent;

import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class MyComponent extends Pane {

    private Node view;
    private MyComponentController controller;

    public MyComponent() {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("myComponent.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(new Callback<Class<?>, Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object call(Class<?> param) {
                return controller = new MyComponentController();
            }
        });
        try {
            view = (Node) fxmlLoader.load();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
        getChildren().add(view);
    }

    public void setWelcome(String str) {
        controller.textField.setText(str);
    }

    public String getWelcome() {
        return controller.textField.getText();
    }

    public StringProperty welcomeProperty() {
        return controller.textField.textProperty();
    }
}
```

MyComponentController.java

```
package customcontrolexample.myCommponent;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class MyComponentController implements Initializable {

    int i = 0;
    @FXML
    TextField textField;

    @FXML
    protected void doSomething() {
        textField.setText("The button was clicked #" + ++i);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        textField.setText("Just click the button!");
    }
}
```

myComponent.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<VBox xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="customcontrolexample.myCommponent.MyComponentController">
  <children>
    <TextField fx:id="textField" prefWidth="200.0" />
    <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#doSomething" text="B" />
  </children>
</VBox>
```

This code needs to check if there is no memory leak.

Answer (score 2):

Quick answer is <fx:include> tag, however, you would need to set the ChoiceModel in the Controller class.

```
<VBox
  xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"

  fx:controller="fxmltestinclude.ChoiceDemo"
>
  <children>
    **<fx:include source="Choice.fxml" />**
    <ListView fx:id="choices" />
  </children>
</VBox>
```

Comment: Also, check out this document http://fxexperience.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/Introducing-FXML.pdf

Comment: ok, but how would I use Choice.fxml to render each item in the 'choices' list?

Answer (score 2):

[The introduction to fxml chapter on custom components](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#custom_components)

gave me the right hint. My intention was to combine a label a slider and a textfield to one custom LabeledValueSlider component.

Usage example:
see [resources/fx of rc-dukes Self-Driving RC Car Java FX App](https://github.com/rc-dukes/dukes/tree/master/rc-app/src/main/resources/fx)

```
    <LabeledValueSlider fx:id='cannyThreshold1' text="Canny threshold 1" blockIncrement="1" max="2000" min="0" value="20" format="\%.0f"/>
    <LabeledValueSlider fx:id="cannyThreshold2" text="Canny threshold 2"  blockIncrement="1" max="2000" min="0" value="50" format="\%.0f"/>
    <LabeledValueSlider fx:id="lineDetectRho" text="LineDetect rho" blockIncrement="0.01" max="20" min="0" value="0.5" />
    <LabeledValueSlider fx:id="lineDetectTheta" text="LineDetect theta" blockIncrement="0.01" max="5" min="-5" value="0.5" />
    <LabeledValueSlider fx:id="lineDetectThreshold" text="LineDetect threshold" blockIncrement="1" max="200" min="0" value="20" format="\%.0f" />
    <LabeledValueSlider fx:id="lineDetectMinLineLength" text="LineDetect minLineLength"  blockIncrement="1" max="200" min="0" value="50" format="\%.0f"/>
    <LabeledValueSlider fx:id="lineDetectMaxLineGap" text="LineDetect maxLineGap" blockIncrement="1" max="500" min="0" value="50" format="\%.0f"/>
```

[image: 7 LabeledValueSliders]

**FXML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Slider?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>

<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.HBox" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">

    <padding>
        <Insets left="10" right="10" />
    </padding>
    <Label fx:id='label' text="Label for Slider" minWidth="180"/>
    <Slider fx:id='slider' blockIncrement="1" max="100" min="0" value="50" />
    <TextField fx:id="textField" maxWidth="75"/>
</fx:root>
```

**Component Source code**
see [LabeledValueSlider.java](http://see%20https://github.com/rc-dukes/dukes/blob/master/rc-app/src/main/java/org/rcdukes/app/LabeledValueSlider.java)

```
package org.rcdukes.app;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;

/**
 * a Slider with a Label and a value
 * 
 * @author wf
 *
 */
public class LabeledValueSlider extends HBox {
  public static boolean debug=true;
  protected static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory
      .getLogger(LabeledValueSlider.class);
  @FXML
  private Label label;
  @FXML
  private Slider slider;
  @FXML
  private TextField textField;

  String format;


  public String getFormat() {
    return format;
  }

  public void setFormat(String format) {
    textField.textProperty().bind(slider.valueProperty().asString(format));
    this.format = format;
  }

  public double getBlockIncrement() {
    return slider.getBlockIncrement();
  }

  public void setBlockIncrement(double value) {
    slider.setBlockIncrement(value);
  }

  public double getMax() {
    return slider.getMax();
  }

  public void setMax(double value) {
    slider.setMax(value);
  }

  public double getMin() {
    return slider.getMin();
  }

  public void setMin(double value) {
    slider.setMin(value);
  }

  public double getValue() {
    return slider.getValue();
  }

  public void setValue(double value) {
    slider.setValue(value);
  }

  public String getText() {
    return label.getText();
  }

  public void setText(String pLabelText) {
    label.setText(pLabelText);
  }

  public URL  getResource(String path) {
    return getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(path);
  }

  /**
   * construct me
   * see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#custom_components
   */
  public LabeledValueSlider() {
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(
        getResource("fx/labeledvalueslider.fxml"));
    try {
      // let's load the HBox - fxmlLoader doesn't know anything about us yet
      fxmlLoader.setController(this); 
      fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
      Object loaded = fxmlLoader.load();
      Object root=fxmlLoader.getRoot();

      if (debug) {
        String msg=String.format("%s loaded for root %s", loaded.getClass().getName(),root.getClass().getName());
        LOG.info(msg);
      }

      textField.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
      if (format == null)
        setFormat("%.2f");
    } catch (IOException exception) {
      throw new RuntimeException(exception);
    }
  }
}
```