# How to include FXML files in Eclipse runnable JAR export?

Tags: eclipse, jar, javafx

I can successfully run my JavaFX2.2.5 project in Eclipse. However, when I try to JAR the project into a runnable JAR, that JAR file doesn't have the FXML files needed inside it (I can verify this by unzipping the JAR file with WinZip).

How can I include the FXML files when you JAR a project via Eclipse?
I assume the FXML files belong in the bin folder, as they do when running in Eclipse.

Comment: Are you using a plugin to build the runnable JAR like FatJAR for instance? You should put them in the `src` folder either way, the `bin` folder is managed by the IDE.

Comment: Thanks Dreen. I am having trouble pointing to the FXML files in any way other than a relative path. That is why I placed the FXML files in the bin directory. I am not using a plugin to build the JAR file. Maybe I should use the JavaFX SDK and run "javafxpackager -createjar"?

Answer (score 0):

The FXML files go into `src` folder, `bin` is managed by the IDE.

For building runnable applications with JavaFX in Eclipse, you should really check out [e(fx)clipse](http://efxclipse.org/).

Also, [please read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434787/how-to-create-custom-components-in-javafx-2-0-using-fxml/8490764#8490764) about loading FXML.