# not able to find file when program is converted into jar

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, javafx, java-io

I have created an application using javafx.
The main method reads from a file javafxmap.xml. below is the code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CurrentFormParam.param.put("window", "start");
    ControllerFactory.populateControllerList("javafxmap.xml");
    launch();       
}
```

This is running well when i am running this using eclipse. The problem arises when i made a deployable jar out of it. It is trying to find this file from outside jar file. 
I mean if my jar is at location /home/kumar/myprog.jar then it looking for javafxmap.xml at /home/kumar/javafxmap.xml. But my xml file is inside jar itself.

Comment: Make sure that this file is included in the build path when you compile your JAR

Comment: Loko at this SO question, about the same problem you are experiencing: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8490764/4515720

Comment: How are you loading the file `javafxmap.xml`?

Comment: Objects in jars are not files, you cannot use file APIs to access them. Look at `Class.getResource`