# JavaFX: Defining custom controls

Tags: java, javafx

How do you define your own custom control in JavaFX?

Say I have a custom control, for the sake of simplicity, let's just make it a `VBox` with two `Button` in it, and call the whole thing `CustomButton`.

**CustomButton.fxml**

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<VBox>
    <Button text="Custom Button A"/>
    <Button text="Custom Button B"/>
</VBox>
```

Now say my root layout looks like this, I especially want to be able to use the `CustomButton` just as if it was a `Label` or a regular `Button`.

**MainView.fxml**

```
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<HBox>
    <Button text="Main Button"></Button>
    <CustomButton />
</HBox>
```

**Main.java**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainView.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Currently, this results in

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: CustomButton is not a valid type.
```

What do I have to change in order to use my `CustomButton` as a proper control?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create custom components in JavaFX 2.0 using FXML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434787/how-to-create-custom-components-in-javafx-2-0-using-fxml)

Answer (score 1):

I think this question has already an answer here [CustomControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434787/how-to-create-custom-components-in-javafx-2-0-using-fxml), for the answer, in order to use a custom component in your FXML you have to include it with the expression `fx:include` inside your container for exemple :

```
<fx:include source="CustomButton.fxml"/>
```

in this case the component is added **graphically** you can handle it with his own controller, here is the tutoriel [fx:include](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#include_elements)